# Прогресс бар в консоли на Си

Tags: c

Пытаюсь сделать простейший прогрессбар в консоли на Си. Не понимаю как заставить программу обновлять поток вывода прямо во время работы, а не после её окончания.  Примерно что-то такое:

```
void progressBar(int count){
  printf("#");
  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    printf("=");
    sleep(1);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

В данном случае, например count=10, выведется строка #==========, но не последовательно, а только после окончания работы программы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вывод буфферизуется. То есть выводится в консоль не сразу, когда вы отправляете строку на печать. Можно сбрасывать буффер каждую итерацию цикла: `fflush(stdout);`